Amazon S3 CopyObject is calling HeadObject internally and failing
I have a piece of code that is calling S3.Client.copy method. It looks like this method is calling HeadObject internally and it is failing.
_______________________________ test_copy_simple _______________________________

copy_item = {'Bucket': 's3copy-source-bucket', 'Key': '100mb_of_files/00kmt5d7.gz', 'LastModified': '2021-08-03T18:48:49.000000', 'Size': 1048576, ...}
msg_body = {'copy_if': '', 'copy_mode': '300', 'dest_region': 'us-east-1', 'destination_bucket': 's3copy-destination-bucket', ...}
s3_source_client_assumed = <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f03beab4760>
s3_destination_client_assumed = <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f03bd588580>

    def copy_worker(
        copy_item, msg_body, s3_source_client_assumed, s3_destination_client_assumed
    ):
        ...
                    logger.debug(f"copy_source = {copy_source}")
                    logger.debug(f"Checking if copy_source exists")
                    logger.debug(
                        f"Head copy_source returns {s3_source_client_assumed.head_object(Bucket=copy_source['Bucket'], Key=copy_source['Key'])}"
                    )
    
                    # dest_local=<target bucket>, cleansed_copy_item=<target full path>
>                   s3_destination_client_assumed.copy(   # FAILS HERE
                        copy_source,                      # a dict that includes bucket, key, and version info of copy_item
                        dest_local,
                        cleansed_copy_item,
                        SourceClient=s3_source_client_assumed,
                        Config=transfer_config,
                        ExtraArgs={
                            "Tagging": parse.urlencode(tags),
                            "TaggingDirective": "REPLACE",
                        },
                    )

src/copy_task.py:330: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py:450: in copy
    return future.result()
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py:103: in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py:266: in result
    raise self._exception
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py:269: in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3transfer/copies.py:124: in _submit
    response = call_args.source_client.head_object(
../../../../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:565: in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <botocore.client.S3 object at 0x7f03c153feb0>
operation_name = 'HeadObject'
api_params = {'Bucket': 's3copy-source-bucket', 'Key': '100mb_of_files/00kmt5d7.gz', 'VersionId': 'IyArE53DEsd1kJ1KQBIyOAuzmW2jzqpB'}

    def _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params):
        ...
        if http.status_code >= 300:
            error_info = parsed_response.get("Error", {})
            error_code = error_info.get("QueryErrorCode") or error_info.get(
                "Code"
            )
            error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
>           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
E           botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request

This happens during unit testing so S3 resource is mocked, but I can head the buckets and the object to be copied with no problem. However when the S3 client calls HeadObject during CopyObject, it throws a 400 (Bad Request) exception.
It seems like the mocked object are accessible from copy_task.py but boto3 doesn't see them. Any advice?
I first tried actually creating these test object in S3 but then I realized they are mocked. I tried heading copy_source in copy_task.py which works (returns 200).
Expected behaviour is to copy copy_source to dest_local successfully and not observing a 400 (Bad Request) error.
